# C bits shifting short ints

Tags: c, byte

Why result of

```
include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned short int i = 0xff ;
    unsigned short int j;
    j= i<<2;
    printf("%x n%x\n", i, j);
    return 0;
}
```

is j = 3fc ?

if both i and j are short int - so they are 2bytes values, so j shouldnt =fc ??

thx in advance for explanations.
~
~

Answer (score 5):

Shifting 0xff left two bits looks like this:

```
    0000 0000 1111 1111
       0    0    f    f

    0000 0011 1111 1100     -- Shifted left 2 bits.
       0    3    f    c
```

So 0x00ff << 2 = 0x03fc. Everything looks as it should be .

Answer (score 4):

No, 0x3fc is correct.  Note that a byte is two hex digits, so a (16-bit) short has a total of 4 hex digits.

Answer (score 1):

```
0xff << 2 == 0xff * 4 == 0x3fc == 1020
```

Even if they are 2-bytes, they are allowed to hold this small value.

Answer (score 1):

3FC requires only 12 bits to store so it can be stored in 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

C++ makes no guarantee as to the number of bytes in an `unsigned short int`.  It in fact makes almost no guarantee about the size of any type other than `char` which is guaranteed to be 1 byte.

In this case though it's irrelevant because 3fc can be successfully stored in only 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you actually tried to write? (Remember an hex digit is 4 bits only, ie, half a byte)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned short int i = 0xffff;
    unsigned short int j;
    j = i<<8;
    printf("%x  %x\n", i, j);
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs `ffff  ff00`